# Getting wrong result sql select func

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've two tables sale(c_id)(net_amount) and customer_payment(c_id)(received_amount)
I'm getting result 1,80,000 instead of 90,000.
my query is

```
select sum(s.net_amount)-sum (cp.recived_amount) from customer_payments cp
 join sale s on   cp.Customer_id = s.customer_id
```

Comment: If a customer makes zero or multiple payments the results will probably be wrong. Describe the purpose of the query.

Comment: net_ amount is the amount of invoice total
and received_amount for the amount is received total
now I want to sum net and received to get the balence left to be received

Comment: Also if a customer makes multiple purchases how is this represented in your data model?

Comment: example 
your bill amount is 20000
you gave me 5000
so the result should be 15000
understand ?

Comment: post example data that breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(sale.net_amount) FROM sale) - 
    (SELECT SUM(customer_payments.recived_amount) FROM customer_payments)

Comment: same result no effect

Comment: My bad. I miss the fact that there may be multiple instances for a single customer on both table. Query is corrected accordingly

Comment: if I want to also fetch customer name from customer.
it will show the name and balence
example:
Hassan 20000
Nuri 15000

Comment: @Hassan_Jaffrani That's a different query. I suggest you open a new question if you could not find your answer in existing questions.